# How do I embed a plotly chart inside an AgGrid cell?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

There are a few "simple" charts I'd like to draw using Plotly and embed as the content of cells in AgGrid.

I have a prepared html for each plot, but Can't seem to render it when I render the AgGrid.
I am trying various cellRenderers but it's not clear what I need to render this as a chart.

[image]